# Plot Bar graph with multiple series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I currently have three dictionaries that have the same keys but have different values since they are for three different years. I am trying to create a comparison between the years. I was wondering how I could go about plotting all three graphs on the same axis. I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
dt = {'2018':nnum.values, '2019':nnum2.values, '2020':nnum3.values,}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dt,index=nnum.keys())
df1.plot.bar()
```

I am trying to do something along this line since each dictionary contains the same keys but I keep getting an error. Is there anyway to set the index to the keys of the dictionary without having to type it out manually

Comment: What is error here?

Comment: The error says "could not broadcast input array from shape (49) into shape (55)" I was wondering if there was a way to include the missing keys into the diction with a shape of 49

Comment: give me some time please.

Comment: no problem thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `()` for values, convert to lists in dictionary `dt` for dictionary of lists:

```
nnum = {1:4,5:3,7:3}
nnum2 = {7:8,9:1,1:0}
nnum3 = {0:7,4:3,8:5}

dt = {'2018': list(nnum.values()), '2019':list(nnum2.values()), '2020':list(nnum3.values())}
df1=pd.DataFrame(dt,index=nnum.keys())

print(df1)
   2018  2019  2020
1     4     8     7
5     3     1     3
7     3     0     5

df1.plot.bar()
```

EDIT: If there is different length of dictionaries and need new values filled by `0` is possible use:

```
nnum = {1:4,5:3,7:3}
nnum2 = {7:8,9:1,1:0}
nnum3 = {0:7,4:3}

from  itertools import zip_longest

L = [list(nnum.values()), list(nnum2.values()), list(nnum3.values())]
L = list(zip_longest(*L, fillvalue=0))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L,index=nnum.keys(), columns=['2018','2019','2020'])

print(df1)
   2018  2019  2020
1     4     8     7
5     3     1     3
7     3     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I noticed that one of the dictionaries has a few missing keys so one is more than the other, is there anyway to assign 0 to the missing keys?